# Can Nexus/Maven store 32 bit and 64 bit artifacts at the same time?

Tags: java, maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson, nexus

I'm currently using [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) as an artifact repository manager. Artifacts are deployed to Nexus automatically via a build machine running [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). The build machine is a 64 bit whereas my development machine is 32 bit.

I would like to create a 32 bit build slave which would automatically build a 32 bit version of our code (e.g. code which uses JNI). Is there a way for Nexus to store both 32bit and 64bit artifacts?

At the moment it seems to me that the "last build wins" e.g. if I build a snapshot project on a 32 bit machine and then a 64 bit machine, the 64 bit version of the artifact is what projects try to download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better use two classifiers, for 32bit and 64bit. This way you get two artifacts into your maven repository.

On the 32bit machine you set the classifier to 32bit and on the other machine to 64bit.

You can set classifier in the [Maven Jar Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

Comment: Do classifiers work if the 32bit and 64bit are actually separate builds? Looking at my Nexus repository the each build increments a build number, a SNAPSHOT dependency always grabs the highest build number - which may not be the correct architecture.